# Hive : Identification of exact duplicate records

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a requirement.

I have a hive table which has more than 200 columns.

Now i have to write a insert query to load the data to another hive table after removing all identical duplicate records.

I know i can achive it by using row number () over () .

Code snippet

```
Insert into table target 
Select col1,col2..col200 
from
(
Select col1,col2...col200,row_number () over ( partition by col1,col2...col200 order by null ) as rn from source 
) a 
where 
rn=1
```

But this would very lengthy as need to write all 200 columns name multiple time,

Is there any easier solution available?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
Insert into table target 
    Select distinct col1,col2..col200 
    from source ;
```

Comment: Thank you . In case i need to do a partition col1 col2 to col199..Is there any easier option there instead writing 199 cols in partition by

Comment: @Queryguy . . . If they are all the columns, you can use `*`.